# Unable to locate an element using id and rel attribute value

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to locate an element and verify the data in the field. In this instance **I need to retrieve and check the account number which is 101**.

The HTML:

```
<table class="headerInfo">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="25%" valign="top" align="left">
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="label" valign="middle" style="">Account Number</td>
<td></td>
<td id="PAULABU1484216235454TabGroupHeaderTabList082588e97-f753-479d-8789-a34555053938" class="field" valign="top" align="left" style="">
<a rel="PAULABU1484216235454TabGroupHeaderTabList082588e97-f753-479d-8789-a34555053938DropMenu">101</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I've tried the following, however I get a 'NoSuchElementException' error:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("PAULABU1484216235454TabGroupHeaderTabList082588e97-f753-479d-8789-a34555053938"));
```

I've also tried the following (but I get the same error:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[rel='PAULABU1484216235454TabGroupHeaderTabList082588e97-f753-479d-8789-a34555053938DropMenu']"));
```

When I copy the CSS Path:

```
html body form div#tabHeader table tbody tr td table.headerInfo tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td#PAULABU1484216235454TabGroupHeaderTabList082588e97-f753-479d-8789-a34555053938.field a
```

When I copy the Xpath:

```
/html/body/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a
```

I was hoping to locate the elements without using an absolute pathway though.

Comment: try with [contains(text()='Account Number')]  and then get the text of 'a'

Comment: Desire element's id and rel attribute value looks dynamically generated, so you can't locate. use some different locator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desire element's `id` and `rel` attribute value looks dynamically generated, so you can't locate using these. Try using some different locator like as below `xapth` :-

```
.//tr[td[text() = 'Account Number']]//a
```

or

```
.//tr[td[text() = 'Account Number']]//a[contains(@rel, 'TabGroupHeaderTabList')]
```